# Weak RNG vulnerability proving

Tags: solidity, transactions, evm, solidity-0.8.x, foundry

Hi guys I am auditing a smart contract and I found a WeakRNG

[image: a function which has a weak RNG vulnerability]

in order to prove it I have written 2 smart contracts which simulate the work of this function( a bit )

here is the 1 a have changed `block.difficulty` and `block.timestamp` as uints256( maybe its incorrect) but I don't now any other way to fuzz their values to show that it is vulnreble

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.7.6;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import {Test} from "forge-std/Test.sol";

contract HandleSelectWinner is Test {
    function selectWinnerRarity(uint256 block_difficulty) public returns (uint256 rarity) {
        address msg_sender = 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266;
        rarity = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, block_difficulty))) % 100;
        return rarity;
    }

    function selectWinnerIndex(uint256 block_difficulty, uint256 block_timestamp)
        public
        returns (uint256 winnerIndex)
    {
        address msg_sender = 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266;
        winnerIndex = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg_sender, block_timestamp, block_difficulty))) % 4;
        return winnerIndex;
    }
}
```

and here is the second

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.6;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import {Test, console} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {StdInvariant} from "forge-std/StdInvariant.sol";
import {PuppyRaffle} from "../../src/PuppyRaffle.sol";
import {HandleSelectWinner} from "./HandleSelectWinner.t.sol";

contract PuppyRaffleTest is StdInvariant, Test {
    PuppyRaffle puppyRaffle;
    HandleSelectWinner handleSelectWinner;
    uint256 entranceFee = 1e18;
    uint256 block_difficulty;
    uint256 block_timestamp;
    address playerOne = address(1);
    address playerTwo = address(2);
    address playerThree = address(3);
    address playerFour = address(4);
    address feeAddress = address(99);
    uint256 duration = 1 days;

    function setUp() public {
        puppyRaffle = new PuppyRaffle(
            entranceFee,
            feeAddress,
            duration
        );
        handleSelectWinner = new HandleSelectWinner();
        targetContract(address(handleSelectWinner));
    }

    function invariant_testSelectWinnerIsNotRandom() public {
        // msg.sender --const
        // block.timestamp - is set up
        // block.difficulty is setting up
        console.log(handleSelectWinner.selectWinnerIndex(block_difficulty, block_timestamp));
        assert(handleSelectWinner.selectWinnerIndex(block_difficulty, block_timestamp) == 1);
    }

    function invariant_testSelectWinnerRarityIsNotRandom() public {
        // msg.sender -- anvil address
        // block.difficulty is variable
        // uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, block.difficulty))) % 100 = 4
        // abi.decode ?
        console.log(handleSelectWinner.selectWinnerRarity(block_difficulty));
        assert(handleSelectWinner.selectWinnerRarity(block_difficulty) == 4);
    }
}
```

also for some reason I get this error about invalid opcodes !?

```
Failing tests:
Encountered 2 failing tests in test/fuzz/FuzzTests.t.sol:PuppyRaffleTest
[FAIL. Reason: EvmError: InvalidFEOpcode] invariant_testSelectWinnerIsNotRandom() (runs: 257, calls: 3840, reverts: 0)
[FAIL. Reason: EvmError: InvalidFEOpcode] invariant_testSelectWinnerRarityIsNotRandom() (runs: 257, calls: 3840, reverts: 0)
```

Its actually I quite funny situation I see the vulnerability but I can't prove it because have started not long ago 
:).

Comment: Why do you need to write a smart contract to show a vulnerability? I see 2 the block producer can manipulate the timestamp, and msg.sender could be anyone.

Comment: Ismael, as I learned no matter when you do an audit you should provide a proof of concept POC it is one of the main parts of the report

Answer (score 0):

The writeup for First Flight Puppy Raffle is here: https://www.codehawks.com/finding/cloogzlbq01miw9xtmfcfpded

The Attack contract aims to exploit the weak PRNG in the selectWinner function to manipulate the raffle outcome and win the prize. The attack proceeds as follows:

Constructor:

The Attack contract takes the address of the vulnerable PuppyRaffle contract during deployment.
attackRandomness Function:

The function calculates a winnerIndex that would result in the attack contract being selected as the winner. It does this by repeatedly incrementing the toAdd variable until the PRNG generates a winnerIndex equal to playersLength.
The attack contract creates a list of addresses (playersToAdd) with the attack contract's address and a few other addresses.
The attack contract sends a significant amount of ether (1 ether for each additional address) to participate in the raffle with the manipulated player list.
After participating, the attack contract calls selectWinner() to execute the raffle and attempt to win the prize.
Fallback Function and ERC721 Receiver Function:

The contract includes a fallback function to receive Ether and an ERC721 receiver function (onERC721Received). These are not directly related to the attack and are likely included for flexibility in handling different scenarios.
Exploiting the Vulnerability:
The exploit takes advantage of the weak PRNG in the selectWinner function. By carefully manipulating the playersToAdd list and the amount of Ether sent, the attack contract can influence the winnerIndex calculation. If the attack contract succeeds in manipulating the winnerIndex to match its position in the playersToAdd list, it can win the raffle and receive the prize.

However, please note that the effectiveness of the attack may depend on various factors, including the behavior of the weak PRNG and the number of participants in the raffle. It's important to understand that manipulating random numbers in this way is highly discouraged and unethical in real-world scenarios. Always follow ethical practices and respect the intended behavior of smart contracts and applications.

Comment: Thanks, I guess you as same as me when started was tinkering by yourself and learning the same way about attack vectors etc ?

Comment: I have never seen actual PoC on Replay Attacks that is fully elaborated. So hopefully this helps you~